# How to force authentificationHandler return json

Tags: java, json, spring-security

I have a custom authentificationHandler

```
public class MyUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {
    private static final String SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION_KEY = "SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION";

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,
                "Authentication Failed: " + getErrorMessage(request, SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION_KEY));
    }

    private String getErrorMessage(HttpServletRequest request, String key) {
        Exception exception = (Exception) request.getSession().getAttribute(key);

        if (exception instanceof DisabledException) {
            return "BOD/EOD";
        }
        return "another";
    }
}
```

If I input wrong credntials I see following http response:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 401 Authentication Failed: another</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 401</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /application/login. Reason:
<pre>    Authentication Failed: another</pre></p><hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                

</body>
</html>
```

I want to get json response at this case

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
 response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
 response.getWriter().write(JsonUtil.toJson(SOME_OBJECT_HERE));
```

Comment: Please explain how this code answers the question -- that is, what the methods do. At the very least, link to documentation. It's better to teach people who read your answer instead of providing copypasta material and letting them suck away more resources when they can't figure things out.

Answer (score 0):

I like to move the rendering to my controllers rather than using Spring Security's API directly. You can do this by instructing Spring Security to forward the request to a URL. For example:

```
SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler handler = 
        new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler("/401");
handler.setUseForward(true);
```

Now you can create an endpoint that processes the 401. For example, if you are using Spring MVC you might do:

```
@RequestMapping("/401")
@ResponseBody
public Exception 401(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return (Exception) request.getAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION);
}
```

The nice thing about this is you get all the standard support for your controller technology. For Spring MVC, this means you would get content negotiation (i.e. JSON, XML, etc), conversion of the return types, etc.